# Masonry: how to change the default animation to fade in when new items are appended?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, masonry

I'm using masonry by Desandro on a wordpress archive page, along with "Ajax Pagination and Infinite Scroll" plugin by Malinky, in order to create a 3 columns masonry layout that appends posts to the masonry grid after more posts are loaded. However, I do not like the visual effect of new set of posts being appended by sliding them in from top/left corner that masonry defaults to. Instead, I would like them to fade in, one by one at the bottom.

I tried setting the transitionDuration to 0s in order to make the new posts start at the right position, but appart from that, I had no success in making them fade in in succession after they are loaded.

So far I only have this to work with:

```
(function($) {
  $(window).load(function(){
    var $container = $('.grid');
    $container.imagesLoaded( function() {
      $container.masonry({
        itemSelector: '.grid-item',
        transitionDuration: '0s'
      });               
    });
  });   
})( jQuery );
```

Note: inside the infinite scroll plugin I'm using this callback:

```
$('.grid').imagesLoaded( function() {
  $('.grid').masonry('reloadItems').masonry();
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Ok, so I figured it out, if enyone else runs into this problem.
You need to set the transitionDuration to '0s' for both the initial masonry function and the ajax plugin callback function.

```
(function($) {
    $(window).load(function(){
        //masonry
        var $container = $('.grid');
        $container.imagesLoaded( function() {
            $container.masonry({
                itemSelector: '.grid-item',
                transitionDuration: 0
            });             
        });
    }); 

})( jQuery );
```

for ajax callback

```
var $container = $('.grid');
$container.imagesLoaded( function() {
    $container.masonry('reloadItems').masonry({
        itemSelector: '.grid-item',
        transitionDuration: 0
    }); 
});
```

Then set the initial opacity of .grid-item elements to 0 inside your css file, and then set each element to fade to 1 via jQuery, like this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
    $('.grid-item').each(function(fadeInDiv){
        $(this).delay(fadeInDiv * 50).fadeTo(250, 1);
   });
});
```

as well as for ajax callback

```
$('.grid-item').each(function(fadeInDiv){
    $(this).delay(fadeInDiv * 50).fadeTo(250, 1);
});`
```